# ItemAdd runs a few times then stops working until I restart Outlook

Tags: vba, events, outlook

I want to run a code every time a new email arrives in the inbox.

The following code is within 'ThisOutlookSession'

```
Public WithEvents oItems as Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application.Startup()
Set oItems = session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).items
End sub

Private sub oItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item as object) 
Debug.print "New email detected" 
End sub
```

This code runs for 1 - 5 new emails. After that, it won't execute unless I close Outlook and reopen.

It is as if `oItems` loses connection to the 'session'.

Comment: The `NewMailEx` event has been a reliable trigger for me,  I use it to get the `MailID` and use the ID with `GetItemFromID` to get the `MailItem` ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious I'm fairly experienced in Excel VBA but very very new to outlook vba. How exactly do I implement NewMailEx?

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious Thanks Dude/Dudette. This works perfectly and has executed perfectly for the past 50 test emails ive done.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this in `ThisOutlookSession`

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

   Dim oNewMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim appNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
   
   Set appNameSpace = Application.Session
   
   Select Case appNameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection).Class
       Case Is = olMail
           Set oNewMailItem = appNameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
   End Select
   
End Sub
```

The event returns the object ID, the object ID is used to get the object. If the object is an email then it is saved as a local variable.

---

Alternatively, you may not want to 'muddy up' `ThisOutlookSession` so you can use a custom class and expose the mail as a public property.

In `ThisOutlookSession` you'd have:

```
Public cNewMailEx As clsNewMailEx

Private Sub Application.Startup()
    Set cNewMailEx = New clsNewMailEx
End sub
```

In a class module named `clsNewMailEx` you'd have:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents olApp As Outlook.Application
Private pMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Public Property Get NewMailItem() As Outlook.MailItem
    Set NewMailItem = pMailItem
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set olApp = Outlook.Application
End Sub

Private Sub olApp_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
   Dim appNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
   Set appNameSpace = Application.Session
   Select Case appNameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection).Class
       Case Is = olMail
           Set pMailItem = appNameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
   End Select
End Sub
```

Now, anywhere in your application, you can retrieve the new email with `cNewMailEx.NewMailItem`

Comment: Your first answer is great if you're only wanting to do a couple things but thank you for this one it gives a much more robust structure and gives me a bit more experience handling classes in vba - I find them counter intuitive and hard to implement

Answer (score 0):

`NewMailEx` is the preferred alternative for the inbox.

For other folders, you could run `Application_Startup` without closing Outlook.

Remove `Private` from `Private Sub Application_Startup()`.

1 - You may assign `Application_Startup` to a button.

2 - To make manual invoking less frequent call `Application_Startup` from existing code you normally run during the day.